# Network share access denied after STIG/CIS hardening in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, robocopy

I have one windows server from where I was running robocopy and it was working. The source  was a network share from where I was copying some files to this windows server.

After implementing CIS/STIG windows OS benchmark I am not able to perform robocopy operation. It is saying "Access denied". I am not able to understand which point in STIG/CIS caused this. How can I make this working?

I am new to Windows.

Comment: “How can I make this working?” - The only way possible revert each change until it works. You can focus on the STIG(s) that are related to network security but without specific knowledge of which STIGs you resolved we cannot help you.  I fully understand your unable to provide that information so the only solution is to brute force reversal of those changes

Comment: @Ramhound this is what I used for applying STIG benchmark https://github.com/ansible-lockdown/Windows-2019-STIG/tree/devel/tasks

Comment: You will have to reverse each STIG one at a time (manually) until your network share starts to work.  Start with the CATI vulerablties